# Ms Access Gathering data from subdatasheet

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Im trying to find a query which shows only fields with `IS NULL` from a subdatasheet column.

So far I have:

```
SELECT EmployeeId,FirstName,LastName,Salary 
FROM Employee
WHERE ServiceDate IS NULL
```

Within the EmployeeId there is an expandable subdatasheet and I'm trying to figure out how to call upon the "ServiceDate" which is within the subdatasheet to display which employee hasn't got a service.
  I hope this make sense.

EDIT:
Here are the two tables:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LWSh.jpg
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zSVS.jpg

Result I'm after:

```
EmployeeId  FirstName   LastName    Salary
E003        Ken         Moore       $59,000.00
```

Comment: Must be Access -- MySQL doesn't have _subdatasheet_.

Comment: A subdatasheet is just another table that is linked via relational joins in your schema. So for every EmployeeID they could have multiple work hours in WorkTbl or something. The subdatasheet is most likely just another table and you're querying the incorrect table.

Comment: Ahh okay yes there's another table called "Service" but how do I go about getting the EmployeeId,FirstName,LastName,Salary from the Employee table into the query so that I can display which employee hasn't had a service... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the EmployeeID in the Service table?

Comment: No it isn't. It's within the 'Employee' table but the 'Employee' table has the subdatasheet attached to it. Sorry for sounding stupid, just trying to get my head around what Uni Lecturer can't teach...

Comment: Both fields are in the 'Employee' table once expanded. Each service is given an 'ServiceID' and there are four employees with EmployeeID's ranging from 'E001' to 'E004' and employee 'E003' is the employee who hasn't had a service. I hope this makes sense. @Fionnuala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something on these lines:

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeId,Employee.FirstName,Employee.LastName,Employee.Salary 
FROM Employee 
LEFT JOIN Services
ON Employee.EmployeeId = Services.EmployeeId
WHERE Services.EmployeeId IS NULL
```

Do not forget that MS Access has a Find Unmatched query wizard.

You might like to look at:

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah! Thankyou so much! Gives me something to look over on the way to UNI tomorrow! If I had enough rep I'd upvote! @Fionnuala

Comment: Check out Aliases while you are reading, they would make the query a lot neater : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp